# How can I override global PHP.INI settings on shared hosting?

Tags: apache-2.2, shared-hosting, php.ini

I have sharring hosting account on Linux Apache PHP with JustHost.

In my account exists a global `php.ini` that only admin of hosting company can access.

My problem is that when I run php script the warnings + errors printed on webpage.

So I create php.ini in my `www` folder and put 2 lines, but nothing happens:

```
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
```

What should I do to override the global shared hosting `php.ini` settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting these lines in your **.htaccess** file:

```
php_value display_errors 0
php_value display_startup_errors 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible, your hosting provider restricts you from overriding default php.ini. Not always!